# Ajax pass parameters from jsp to servlet

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass a date captured in jquery datepicker from jsp to servlet through Ajax. The date is being passed as an object instead of the value.

The following is the jsp and servlet code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>   
 <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.*" %>
 <%@page import="Remote.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TAS Admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    #header-wrap {
        position: fixed;
        height: 92px;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        background-color: #000099;
    }

    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .form-group input
    {
    width:150px;
    }
    .details
    {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    .datedetails
    {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    .report
    {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    h1 {
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
#name {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.3em rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="datedetails">
<!-- <form action="JobHistory" method="post"> -->
<table border=0 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 align=center width=100% bgcolor=#EFEFEF style=border-radius:5px;>
        <col width=30%>
        <col width=30%>
        <col width=20%>
        <col width=20%>
    <tr>
        <td><center><b>From Date:</b> <input type="text" id="fromdate" name="fromdate" style="width:90px;"/></center></td>
        <td><center><b>To Date:</b> <input type="text" id="todate" name="todate" style="width:90px;" /></center></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><center><input type="submit" value="Go" style="width:50px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="fetchData()"/></center></td>
    </tr>
 </table>

<!-- </form>-->
</div>
<div class="bs-example">
<table class="dataTable" id="dataReport" >
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Location No</th>
                <th>Public IP</th>
                <th>Gateway IP</th>
                <th>Purpose</th>
                <th>Submitted by</th>
                <th>Submitted Date</th>
            </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
<script>

/*var fromdate=$('#fromdate').datepicker().val();
var todate = $('#todate').datepicker().val();*/

/*var todate=$("#todate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate").val();
            document.getElementById("todate").value=date;
        }
        });*/

/*var fromdate=$("#fromdate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
        var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate").val();
        document.getElementById("fromdate").value=date;
    }
    });*/

    var fromdate=$("#fromdate").datepicker({
        onSelect:function(dateText, inst) {  var frmdate= dateText; }
        });

    var todate= $("#todate").datepicker({
        onSelect:function(dateText, inst) { var tdate= dateText; }
        });


function fetchData(){

    var datastring='fromdate='+fromdate+'&todate='+todate; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: datastring,
        url: "JobHistory",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: AjaxFetchDataSucceeded,
        error: AjaxFetchDataFailed

    });
}

function AjaxFetchDataSucceeded(result) {
    if (result != "[]") {
        //var dataTab = $.parseJSON(result);
        $("#dataReport").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aaData": result,
            //important  -- headers of the json
            "aoColumns": [{ "mDataProp": "locnid","sWidth" : "5%","bSortable" : true  }, 
                          { "mDataProp": "public_ip","sWidth" : "5%","bSortable" : true  },
                          { "mDataProp": "gate_ip","sWidth" : "5%","bSortable" : true  },
                          { "mDataProp": "comment","sWidth" : "10%","bSortable" : true  }, 
                          { "mDataProp": "userid","sWidth" : "5%","bSortable" : true  },
                          { "mDataProp": "job_date","sWidth" : "5%","bSortable" : true  },],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bDestroy": true

        });
    }
}

function AjaxFetchDataFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

History.java

```
package Remote;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import java.util.*;
    import Remote.connection;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import com.google.gson.*;
    /**
     * Servlet implementation class JobHistory
     */
    @WebServlet("/JobHistory")
    public class JobHistory extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public JobHistory() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("application/json");  
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            ArrayList<Report> report = new ArrayList<Report>();

            String frmdate=request.getParameter("fromdate");
            String todate=request.getParameter("todate");

            HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
            String userid=(String)session.getAttribute("username");
            String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
            String zAdmin = (String) session.getAttribute("zAdmin");
            String tAdmin = (String) session.getAttribute("tAdmin");

            Connection con=null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            ResultSet rs=null;

            String mysql="";
            if(user.equals("Y"))
            {
                mysql="select locnid,public_ip,gate_ip,userid,comment from connections where job_date between "+frmdate+" and "+todate;
                //mysql="select locnid,public_ip,gate_ip,comment,userid,job_date from connections";
            }
            else if(zAdmin.equals("Y"))
            {
                mysql="select locnid,public_ip,gate_ip,comment,userid,job_date from connections where locnid in (select location from zmgr where empid=?) and job_date between "+frmdate+"and "+todate+
                       "union"+
                       "select locnid,public_ip,gate_ip,comment,userid,job_date from connections where userid=? and job_date between "+frmdate+" and "+todate;
            }
            else if(tAdmin.equals("Y"))
            {
                mysql="select locnid,public_ip,gate_ip,comment,userid,job_date from connections where userid=? and job_date between "+frmdate+" and "+todate;
            }

            try{
                con=new connection().getConnection();
                pstmt=con.prepareStatement(mysql);
                if(zAdmin.equals("Y")||tAdmin.equals("Y"))
                pstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(userid));
                rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
                int i=1;
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    report.add(new Report(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4)!=null?rs.getString(4):" ",rs.getString(5)!=null?rs.getString(5):" ",rs.getString(6)));

                    //i++;
                }
                con.close();
                String json=new Gson().toJson(report);
                out.print(json);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

The parameters which are sent from jsp through ajax are not appearing in "fromdate" and "todate" variables in the servlet.
Please let me know the issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

var datastring should be in json format:

```
var datastring= {};
datastring.fromdate=fromdate;
datastring.todate=todate;
```

It is because "'fromdate='+fromdate+'&todate='+todate" means a part of url query by using GET method.   But you are using a POST method.